# R libraries installation

Tags: r

I am using a computer where I have read only rights for the R library folder.
When I am installing new packages I therefore use

```
libpath <- "c:/R/mylibraries"
.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), libpath) )
install.packages("htmltools",   lib=libpath)
```

always when I am installing a new packages with dependecies (like e.g. htmltools depends on lme4), I get erros like:

```
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘lme4’
```

although lme4 is installed and I used it before....
also other errors/warnings like:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘Rcpp’
```

or:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘c:\...\file17b033a54a21\jsonlite’ to ‘c:\...\jsonlite’
```

occur. If I install them twice they usually work but sometimes dependencies to packages that worked before are lost and I have to reinstall them again. 
Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a file named `.REnviron` in your `Documents` folder and restart R:

```
R_LIBS=c:/R/mylibraries
```

From then on, you should be able to install packages into that location automatically, without having to fiddle around with `.libPaths`.

Comment: For reference, there are a number of other (system-wide or per-user) location and setting choices.  See `help(Startup)` in R.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel correct of course, but this is probably the best solution (ie, least likely to break anything) fora newbie on Windows.