# How to create .Renviron file?

Tags: r

I need to use my user defined folder where I stored my packages. I have referred the link given below.

[R libraries installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344588/r-libraries-installation/40787111#40787111)

I have applied the same but it didn't work for me. I have created a file called .Renviron with data R_LIBS=c:/Rpackages ,where my packages installed. But, still it is showing there is no such package 'RODBC' exists. Also, I put this file in my Documents folder in C drive and tried. That also gave the same error. Still the file type is showing as text document. How to change this file type?

Answer (score 26):

#### On mac (or linux)

Open the terminal and type

```
touch $HOME/.Renviron
```

To open the file you just created, navigate through finder to `/Users/<your-user-name>/.Renviron`, or simply open the terminal and type

```
open $HOME/.Renviron
```

#### On windows

Click on start and open powershell. Copy this code into powershell

```
Add-Content c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\.Renviron "TEST_VARIABLE_1=my_username"
Add-Content c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\.Renviron "TEST_VARIABLE_2=123"
```

You'll now have a file called `.Renviron` located in the `Documents` folder. **Close and reopen RStudio**. Then run `Sys.getenv('TEST_VARIABLE_1')` to access the variable in R (obviously that works for any other environment variables you set as well).

Answer (score 20):

It may be worth adding that package [**`usethis`**](https://usethis.r-lib.org/) now offers a series of function facilitating easy editing and opening of R startup files. Family of [`edit_*`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/edit.html) functions can be used to conveniently edit desired startup and configuration files. To edit `.Renviron`, which is appropriate place to store the relevant configuration use:

```
# Edit Renviron
usethis::edit_r_environ()
# You can also consider creating project-specific settings:
usethis::edit_r_environ(scope = "project")
```

*Usethis* provides other functions useful for managing R configuration. For instance in order to edit `Makevars` you can do:

```
# Edit .R/Makevars
usethis::edit_r_makevars()
```

Answer (score 16):

Look at `help(Startup)` which has an example at the end:

```
 ## Example ~/.Renviron on Unix
 R_LIBS=~/R/library
 PAGER=/usr/local/bin/less

 ## Example .Renviron on Windows
 R_LIBS=C:/R/library
 MY_TCLTK="c:/Program Files/Tcl/bin"

 ## Example of setting R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES (from R CMD check)
 R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES='utils,grDevices,graphics,stats'
 # this loads the packages in the order given, so they appear on
 # the search path in reverse order.
```

But note the spelling: `Renviron` with lower case e.  Just use a text editor and edit the file.  Also note that R has a variant in one of its system folder `etc/` below its `RHOME`:

```
edd@bud:~$ R RHOME
/usr/lib/R
edd@bud:~$ cat $(R RHOME)/etc/Renviron.site
##                                              Emacs please make this -*- R -*-
## empty Renviron.site for R on Debian
##
## Copyright (C) 2008 Dirk Eddelbuettel and GPL'ed
##
## see help(Startup) for documentation on ~/.Renviron and Renviron.site

# ## Example ~/.Renviron on Unix
# R_LIBS=~/R/library
# PAGER=/usr/local/bin/less

# ## Example .Renviron on Windows
# R_LIBS=C:/R/library
# MY_TCLTK="c:/Program Files/Tcl/bin"

# ## Example of setting R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES (from R CMD check)
# R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES='utils,grDevices,graphics,stats'
# # this loads the packages in the order given, so they appear on
# # the search path in reverse order.
edd@bud:~$
```

Hm. Looks like I wrote that for the Debian package and it does always exist.  You can still copy it.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac
The **Renviron** file is located in

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/etc/
```

Creating a .Renviron file in the User's home directory will not help.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct, you can override the system wide settings with per user or per project files - see support docs at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf