# Unable to change the Python to be used for interacting with R using reticulate

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, reticulate

I want to use a specific Python version: `/Users/aviral.s/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python`. This version is not available for R.

I tried reading the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html) but following all the three steps(setting the env variable, using the API `use_python()` didn't help either.

With `sudo`, I run the following code:

```
library("reticulate")
py_config()
use_python("/Users/aviral.s/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python")
py_config() # Unchanged.
```

I tried using any of the available ones in the py_config() which worked by setting the environment variable as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547674/10834788)

However, if I set the same env variable to my `pyenv` version, I get this error:

```
> library("reticulate")
> py_config()
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) :
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

My env variable is correct:

```
echo $RETICULATE_PYTHON
/Users/aviral.s/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a few days ago and i had to jump through all kinds of hoops to get where i wanted and i am not sure which one did it for me, but what definitely helped was using `py_discover_config()` instead of the regular `py_config()` command.

what might be another problem, is that apparently a python version with installed numpy will always be preferred by reticulate:

[image: Python info]