# R Reticulate transformers library cannot find torch

Tags: r, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, reticulate

Using R and the `reticulate` package I am trying to use a pre-trained model from Huggingface. This partcular model requires PyTorch and transformers. Both are available in R via reticulate, however even though I can install and load both, the transformers package can't find the PyTorch installation.

```
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
reticulate::py_install('transformers', pip = TRUE)
reticulate::py_install("PyTorch")

transformer = reticulate::import('transformers')
torch = reticulate::import('torch')
tokenizer = transformer$AutoTokenizer$from_pretrained("gagan3012/keytotext-small")
model = transformer$AutoModel$from_pretrained("gagan3012/keytotext-small")
```

and the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): ImportError: 
AutoModel requires the PyTorch library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the
installation page: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and follow the ones that match your environment.


Detailed traceback:
  File "/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/utils/dummy_pt_objects.py", line 364, in from_pretrained
    requires_backends(cls, ["torch"])
  File "/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 683, in requires_backends
    raise ImportError("".join([BACKENDS_MAPPING[backend][1].format(name) for backend in backends]))

Traceback:

1. transformer$AutoModel$from_pretrained("gagan3012/keytotext-small")
2. py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
```

but PyTorch is definitely installed - I can call methods i.e `torch$cudnn_convolution_add_relu` so how can I tell the transformers package where torch is?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reticulate is pointing to miniconda, and you have likely installed PyTorch, etc. in a different environment.

Check out which python environment your `Pytorch` is installed. Then check where your reticulate environment is using `Sys.getenv()` and look for `RETICULATE_PYTHON` variable.

The best way to handle a mis-match is to create a .Renviron file in the home directory listed in your `Sys.getenv()`

I install all of my packages into a Python environment called reticulate and then point to it in my `.Renviron` file.

In your `.Renviron` file you need the following code:

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="path to environment with Pytorch"
```

This post talks about it also.

[.Renviron File for Reticulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145643/unable-to-change-python-path-in-reticulate/69798951#69798951)