# Not able to create .REnviron file

Tags: r

I need to use my user defined folder where I stored my packages. I have referred the link given below.

[R libraries installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344588/r-libraries-installation/40787111#40787111)

I have applied the same but it didn't work for me. I have created a file called .REnviron with data R_LIBS=c:/Rpackages ,where my packages installed. But, still it is showing there is no such package 'RODBC' exists. Also, I put this file in my Documents folder in C drive and tried. That also gave the same error. Still the file type is showing as text document. How to change this file type?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Julie

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788645/how-to-create-renviron-file/

Comment: The comment I made before still holds. You have to install RODBC _after_ creating the .Renviron file.